# How to get names of all subfolders in a Firebase folder in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

In my Firebase Storage, the file hierarchy is like this:

```
Folder
    - Subfolder1
        - File1
        - File2
    - Subfolder2
        - File1
        - File2
        - File3
     - Subfolder3
        - File1
        - File2
```

etc...

So what I want is, I want to get the names of the sub folders in the main folder into an array. So the array will look like :

> folderNamesArray = ["Subfolder1", "Subfolder2", "Subfolder3"]

Does anyone know a way to do this? I tried looking in the documentation, but wasn't able to find any solution under the relevant topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from the [`DataSnapshot.Value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1a45e32265ebf6ad5ee66848b425e9a934) in your case is an [`IDictionary<string, object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2) so you could probably simply get all [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.keys#system-collections-generic-idictionary-2-keys) and convert them to an array like

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] folderNames = snapshot.Value.Keys.ToArray();
```

or if you rather want the actual snapshots of these you could simply use [`DataSnapshot.Children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1ae4827fb6022f78793c8cfd2a9f6cc488)

```
using System.Linq;

...

DataSnapshot[] folders = snapshot.Children.ToArray();

// And then if needed you could still do
string[] folderNames = folders.Select(f => f.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not supported yet for Unity Firebase Storage. The function name is ListAll.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/98